# Wordpress change default translation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation

I want to change the translation value of a text when the language is the default English USA locale.
What is the correct way to accomplish this so we don't have to change the file every time we upgrade the wordpress version?

Comment: Is this for WordPress itself or a plugin?

Comment: @doublesharp It is a text in a plugin. It is a text in woo commerce for example which I want to change but the value is fetched from translation. I thought changing the value in translation file might be the solution.

Comment: Is it not translated properly, or do you just want a different translation?

Comment: I need a different translation.

Comment: Changes the translations files in WooCommerce will be overwritten if you upgrade, you will need to post some code samples for the section you want to change to see if there is a work around.

Comment: But overall if I want to change the default translation value of something in wordpress which file do I change or what file do I generate?

Comment: They are in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce-admin.pot` and `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce.pot`. You can edit it with http://www.poedit.net/

Comment: If you change the specific strings a bit you can use this method as well http://blog.ftwr.co.uk/archives/2010/01/02/mangling-strings-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: I have written a plugin that does just that ( meaning you can choose  offers an alternative translations for everything ), but I have never released it actually . If I have time this week I will clean it up and post it ..

Answer (score 8):

This is a nice plugin that does just that: http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-localization/

But if you have only a few, you can also use this code:

```
function filter_gettext($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ( $text == 'Recent Comments' ) {
        $translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        return $translations->translate( 'Something else' );
    }
    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'filter_gettext', 10, 4);
```